# In firebase real-time database, how can I debug the spikes in usage load?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, load, firebase-console

Multiple clients(webApp, mobileApp) are consuming the data directly from real-time database.

Look at the attached graph below, there is no variation in either `database connections` or `download` usage during the spike in database load.

And also we did't do any code change in client/server(function) for the last couple of months.

I couldn't figure out; what is causing the load in database usage!

How can I debug this issue?

Appreciate your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll Now a days I don't see these random spikes frequently.

Answer (score 1):

After handling something similar to this issue for a long time and contacting pretty much every one in the Firebase support system I reached the following insights:

1. **Realtime DB queries:** Firebase realtime database can not handle querying massive amounts of data (>5 million nodes for example) whether you index it or not. To solve this issue make sure you are indexing on the least amount of endpoints as possible.
2. **Cold starts:** Sometimes functions take a while to start and can get a bit back-logged. Once they start running they will cause loads on the database itself. There is no solution to this issue but you should optimise your functions to take the shortest amount of time possible (see: [Firebase cloud code functions tips & tricks)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#write_idempotent_functions).
3. **Firebase support**: Talk to the Firebase support, they can usually point you in the right direction.

For me what helped most was removing the unnecessary indexOn rules, upgrading to nodeJS 10, and expanding memory limits for some cloud functions. In addition, I am now on the path to switch to Firestore as my backend solution.